# TMaskEdit preenchendo da direita para esquerda

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-10

Estou fazendo um projeto em delphi que utiliza editmask. Estou usando a mascara de telefone.
Quando se clica no edit para escrever o telefone, ele vai pro ultimo campo da direita, assim sendo necessário voltar com o backspace até inicio do edit na esquerda.

Gostaria de colocar um jeito que quando o usuário digitasse o numero no ultimo campo da direita, ele fosse passado para esquerda. Assim sucessivamente até completar o campo de telefone. Seria possível?

Usando um exemplo de como seria:

[imagem 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqICq.png)

[imagem 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucNJC.png)
[imagem 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rili.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verifique a propriedade `BiDiMode`, ela é a responsável por este comportamento.
Por padrão ela é definida como: **bdLeftToRight**

Para configurações adicionais ver na [documentação oficial](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.BiDiMode).